# Does FIRST() aggregate filter out NULL value in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

In the document, the [description](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#syntax-aggfunctions) is as follows

`Returns the first sequential value in the scope of the function.`

However unlike other aggregates, it didn't say whether its scope include NULL value or not. I did some experiment, and just from experiment result it seems it is indeed filtering out NULL value, but still just want to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

From SQL standpoint NULL is the term used to represent a missing value. Thus a field with a NULL “value” is a field with no value so it makes sense it is not considered by FIRST() aggregation

Confirming, from my experience, that NULL is not considered by FIRTST()

Agree, this would be better to clearly reflected in documentation